# Calendar 2 ionic

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, calendar

I have a calendar on my ionic app and there is an API that brings me events from database.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://portalemme2.com.br/SaoJoseAPI/agenda', true);

this.http.get('http://portalemme2.com.br/SaoJoseAPI/agenda').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(vetor => {
    this.eventos = vetor.eventos;
});
```

How can I change the date format to appear on calendar?

Every event has an date like '2018-01-01' and an hour like '01:00:00.0000000' (from database)

But the calendar from ionic only accepts date in this format '2017-12-16 01:00:00'

I need to transform all dates to push in "this.eventos" array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com), an excellent and easy to use library to manipulate dates. You should use data returned from the server to construct a Moment object pasing them to the moment() function and then, use `format` method to convert date to the format required by Calendar. In your case, to convert to these format, you should pass to format method something like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

Comment: But I receive other data from the event, like name, information... how can I use moment.js just in date?

Comment: You should extract date information and pass to moment. Can you paste an example of data received?

Comment: [{…}]
0
:
data_final
:
"2018-01-01"
data_inicio
:
"2018-01-01"
excluido
:
0
hora_final
:
"01:00:00.0000000"
hora_inicio
:
"00:00:00.0000000"
id
:
7
info
:
"Ano novo "
nome_evento
:
"Ano novo"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: Ok, supose that you want to generate init date and you have stored this example in "event" variable, you could call moment like: moment(event.data_inicio + " " + event.hora_inicio, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"). The second parameter indicates format that you are passing.

Comment: Great!! I'm glad. Could you mark the answer as correct, please?